# Rails 3.1. How to prevent Rails to use CoffeScript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

How do I prevent Rails to enable CoffeeScript and use plain JavaScript instead?

Comment: Presumably you got a good reason. Coffeescript rocks... Learning curve 0 for someone from a JS background

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Comment out `gem 'coffee-script'` in Gemfile

Comment: To clarify something that puzzled me (as explained in an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722195)), the CoffeeScript gem will still get pulled into your `Gemfile.lock` if you're using other gems that require it, notably uglifier and Rails 4's Turbolinks. But commenting it out in `Gemfile` will stop the generators from creating `.js.coffee` files and they'll make `.js` files instead.

Answer (score 19):

Just name your files `.js` instead of `.js.coffee`. This is a Tilt naming convention. Similarly, if you don't want to use SCSS, use `.css` instead of `.css.scss`. Or if you'd rather use the Sass syntax with semantic whitespace, use `.css.sass`.

By default, `.js.coffee` files are created by certain commands (notably `generate controller`) as long as `gem 'coffee-script'` is in the Gemfile, so you'll want to comment that out.

Answer (score 3):

Comment out
    `# gem "coffee-script"`
in your gemfile
or just use .js vs .js.coffee files