# Rails 3.1: Do I need to use CoffeeScript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass, coffeescript

Do I need to use CoffeeScript instead of JS in a Rails 3.1 app? The same goes for SASS and CSS.

thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112155/rails-3-1-how-to-prevent-rails-to-use-coffescript

Comment: @VictorDeryagin That link appears to be NSFW. (After translation anyway)

Comment: @PeteHerbertPenito thanks, that link is expired.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you don't. Just remove the coffeescript and sass gems in the Gemfile and you are good to go.

Comment: But give coffeescript a try. You don't have to use it if you don't want but it's worth knowing how it works. If you plan to work in Rails you will come across coffeescript more and more.

Comment: CoffeeScript is just a default in Rails 3.1