# How can I completely disable CoffeeScript in a Rails 3.1 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

At the moment when I generate a new controller, Rails also generates a `.js.coffee` file for the controller as well. As I don't use CoffeeScript I want Rails instead generate `.js` files for me.

Is it enough to comment out the `coffee-rails` gem to completely disable CofeeScript in a Rails 3.1 app?

Comment: You can get a list of all coffeescript files with `find . -iname '*.coffee'`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

1. Comment out `gem "coffee-script"` in your Gemfile
2. Use .js instead of .js.coffee for your javascript files

Comment: Is this documented somewhere that commenting out the `coffee-script` gem is enough?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out?

Comment: I don't have that line in my Gemfile, but I still needed to install a JS engine in production to compile assets (using Capistrano with the `load 'deploy/assets'` line). Sort of annoying.

Comment: No, removing the gem from your gemfile does NOT work.  Keeping your cofeescript outside 'assets' seems to be the only way (which is utterly frustrating)

Comment: In Rails 4, removing `coffee-rails` may result in `cannot load such file -- coffee_script` errors due to stale coffee files in the `tmp/cache/assets` folder.  Run `rake assets:clobber` to remove them.

Comment: In general, removing the item from the Gemfile should work, but there are caveats. `coffee-script` may be a dependency of another GEM. The best place to check for dependencies is `./Gemfile.lock`.  For example: `coffee-rails` is a dependency of `turbolinks`, and `coffee-script` is a dependency of `coffee-rails`. So, if you remove `gem 'coffee-script'` from the Gemfile, but  if you have `gem 'turbolinks''`, CoffeeScript will still be installed.

Comment: also if you use something like active_admin, coffescript is included as dependency there as well so this does not only apply to standard rails gems. Safest to use `config.generators do { |g| g.javascript_engine :js }`

Comment: `config.generators` seems like the right way to do it.

Comment: Before remove from gemfile, execute rake tmp:cache:clear

Answer (score 28):

Not sure if this counts for Rails 3.1 but in 4 you should also set the `javascript_engine` to `:js` in `application.rb` to instruct generators to create `.js` files instead of `.js.coffee`.

```
config.generators do |g|
  # .. other configuration ..
  g.javascript_engine :js
end
```

Comment: You can do this on one line, too: `config.generators.javascript_engine :js`

Comment: This no longer appears to be necessary in Rails 4.1.  Simply removing  'gem coffee-rails' from the Gemfile is enough.

Comment: It is still necessary even in Rails 4.1 if you have a transitive dependency on coffee-rails such as activeadmin

Comment: This no longer necessary in Rails 4.2.4

Comment: It's necessary even in Rails 4.2.6. Without that, it generates coffeescript files.

Comment: this should be the top answer

Answer (score 1):

Koen and Gaurav Gupta have good answers!

If you want to make these changes automatically for every new Rails project, you can use a template file.

In `~/rails-template.rb`

```rb
# Don't install coffeescript
gsub_file 'Gemfile', /^gem \'coffee-rails\'/ do
  "\# gem 'coffee-rails'"
end

# Mess with generators to get the behavior we expect around new files
# For these injections, indentation matters!
inject_into_file 'config/application.rb', after: "class Application < Rails::Application\n" do
  <<-'RUBY'
    config.generators do |g|
      # Always use .js files, never .coffee
      g.javascript_engine :js
    end
  RUBY
end
```

Then in `~/.railsrc`

```
-m ~/.rails-template.rb
```

Now whenever you run `rails new`, the coffeescript gem will be commented out, and new controllers will use `.js` instead of `.coffee`.

Tested on Rails 5.0.4, but I believe it should work for earlier versions as well.

---

As an aside, [Rails templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html), and [generators in general](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#generator-methods), are super powerful. I'm a teacher and my students will typically create 15 to 20 rails projects through the course, and providing them with a good template file with debugging gems, spec style testing, etc. is a huge timesaver. After they've made the changes once themselves, of course. If you're interested, my personal `.rails-template.rb` is [on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/droberts-ada/26a3bff1510b0b45fa5dd764a833483c).

Answer (score -1):

Note for Rails 4, or if you're using 'turbolinks', 'uglifier', or any other kind of gem that requires the server to interpret javascript, comment them out as well.

Comment: You may still want turbolinks or uglifier, even if you aren't still using CoffeeScript in your own source code.

Answer (score -4):

I had this problem, as I am using codekit to compile my coffeescript.

I got around it by renaming my 'assets/coffee' folder to 'assets/cafe', so rail wouldn't find it.

Edit: What does work (and the ONLY thing that works for me, the above answer does not work) is to add a separate folder 'App/Coffee', and setting it to be compiled into the assets/javascript folder.  If it's in the assets directory, rails will find it no matter the name.

Comment: Damn, scratch that after restarting rails it's found assets/cafe and is trying to compile it again.