# Configure Ruby on Rails to generate .js not js.coffee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, coffeescript

Is there a way to configure ruby on rails to generate .js files and not .js.coffee when generating a new controller. I don't want to use CoffeeScript, and it's annoying having to refactor all my files.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

from [How can I completely disable CoffeeScript in a Rails 3.1 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722195/how-can-i-completely-disable-coffeescript-in-a-rails-3-1-app)

```
Comment out gem "coffee-script" in your Gemfile
Use .js instead of .js.coffee for your javascript files
```

Comment: Removing coffee-script in my gemfile did the trick. Thanks

Comment: This broke things on my app. I am using Devise plugin and the `sign_in` page wouldn't load.

Comment: I think this is a better answer. It shouldn't break any dependencies that need coffee-script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232570/how-to-configure-rails-3-2-4-to-generate-js-instead-of-js-coffee-by-default