# How to configure Rails 3.2+/4 to generate .js instead of .js.coffee by default?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have seen a number of variations of this question where all the answers simply suggest removing the `coffee-rails` gem from the `Gemfile` ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722195/how-can-i-completely-disable-coffeescript-in-a-rails-3-1-app) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112155/rails-3-1-how-to-prevent-rails-to-use-coffescript)).

This is not the answer that I am looking for. I may still want to write some CoffeeScript in the project, I just want JavaScript (`.js`) to be the default for the Rails generators.

This also means the suggestions to *rename `.js.coffee` to `.js`* **every time** I generate code is not a desirable solution.

Is there some sort of configuration in Rails I can change to make `.js` the default, but still leave CoffeeScript enabled (Asset Pipeline should still be able to transpile an `.js.coffee` files that I may write)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this by [customising the generators config](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow).

#### config/application.rb

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.javascript_engine :js
end

# or
config.generators.javascript_engine = :js
```

You can see more available configuration options [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a8a3a8cc691facad4ba7487a7b66362b498720c9/guides/source/configuring.md#configuring-generators).

Comment: I tried both of the above solutions and they both work great. It was just a matter of sticking either one inside the `Application` class of `config/application.rb`.

Comment: @jbranchaud great to hear!

Answer (score -1):

Comment out `gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'` in your Gemfile

Comment: I am not interested in disabling CoffeeScript, I just don't want it to be the Rails generator default. By removing that gem, my existing CoffeeScript code no longer gets transpiled and included in pages.