# Rails4 without coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I'm attempting to optimize rails for my development habits a bit better.  As a javascript (not coffeescript) user, I have no use for the controller-specific .js.coffee files that are automatically generated with a new controller.  (If rails wanted to automatically generate controller-specific .js files, that would certainly be cool)

**My Question(s):**

- How do I configure Rails 4 to stop using coffeescript?  I saw in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722405/2540204) that disabling it in rails3 involved removing `gem "coffee-script"`.  This gem was not found in my gemfile but there IS another coffeescript gem in there: `coffee-rails`.  Would I be correct in assuming that I should just disable that one?
- In whichever way you recommend to disable coffeescript, does that actually disable the ability for rails to read coffeescript?  Or does that simply mean that it no longer defaults to coffeescript?  (Either one is fine, but I'd appreciate if you could specify.)
- Are there any considerations or potential pitfalls that make this change in configuration a bad idea?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: At 800+ rep and 2+ years on the site, you should know that you're expected to do some searching for existing questions before asking new ones. This is an *incredibly* well-covered topic: https://www.google.ca/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+use+rails+without+coffeescript

Comment: @meagar While I appreciate your aim of preventing duplicate questions, I don't think it's quite correct to call this question a duplicate.  As you surely know, rails has changed a good deal from version 3 to version 4 and this change has (as far as I can tell) invalidated the selected answer to the question you've referenced.  Though I'm inclined to refer to your discretion as you've certainly earned a great deal of seniority on this site, I'm not sure that this particular question has yet been covered.