# Rails 5.1.6 can't start: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just woken up and can't start the rails server using **rails s**. I get the following error:

```
$ rails s
c:/Sites/wtna/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

All was running fine 10 hours ago. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post your code from your `application.rb` file as well? it could be that the `config` variable is being tried to be accessed outside the scope where it was defined.

Comment: did you change something in the last 10 hours? did someone else change something and you pulled it down with a git/svn update?

Comment: Thanks, guys. There was a line I had added yesterday to application.rb which, once commented out, gets me running again (see below).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that commenting out the following line in **config/application.rb** (which I took from dotdotdotPaul: [How can I completely disable CoffeeScript in a Rails 3.1 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722195/how-can-i-completely-disable-coffeescript-in-a-rails-3-1-app)) cured the problem:

```
config.generators.javascript_engine :js
```