# Rail 3.2 with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new in Rails 3.2. I do not know how I can use javascript with Rails 3.2. There are assets file in it and in assets file there is a file is called javascript. However, in this file, document names are `controller_name.js.coffee`. Thus, I need to help. How can I manage my javascript+jQuery code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an out-of-the-box Rails 3.1+ app, the `application.js.coffee` file brings in all the other `.js` and `.js.coffee` files with the

```
# require_tree .
```

Sprockets directive. In development mode, this serves all of your JS files separately. In production, it concatenates them.

If you want to use JavaScript instead of CoffeeScript, simply replace the `.js.coffee` extensions with `.js`. (Don't forget to replace the `#`-style comments with `//`-style ones.)

I hope that gives you enough information to get started. For more information, consult the official guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: so, can i use JS like Rails 3.0 usage because i don not want to struggle with assets pipeline.

Comment: You could, but you wouldn't want to. The asset pipeline makes it extremely easy to do things like minification that previously required either manual effort or additional plugins. You can change the default extension from `.js.coffee` to `.js` by removing the CoffeeScript gem; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6113524/66226